# Hibernate one to many multiple tables

Tags: mysql, database, hibernate

I'm trying to design a system for giving users permissions on objects. Currently I have a database schema where there are roles and each role can have a permission on multiple 'securable objects'. Such an object can be a sensor, an other user or whatever new thing we might add later. So I have a table role_permissions that links a role to a user, sensor etc. A user can also have a permission directly, so there would also be a user_permissions table that link a user directly to a user, sensor etc.
Now the field that refers to a securable object can't be a foreign key, because the target objects can be of different types and thus come from different tables.

The problem I'm facing right now is how I can make Hibernate work with this. One-to-many relations won't work here I think because Hibernate can't possibly know in which table to look.

An alternative would be to create a role_user_permissions table, a role_sensor_permissions table, a user_user_permissions talbe, a user_sensor_permissions table, and a new role_other_type_permissions table + user_other_permissions table for every securable type that's in the system. So for every single type that needs to have permissions on it I would need 2 new tables to manage the permissions.
But now the database is cluttered with permissions tables that actually serve the exact same purpose but for different types. However, Hibernate IS happy to take this because through foreign keys it always knows what table to look in and what type the object is.

Does anyone know a best practice to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance,
Stan

Comment: Could you give your setting file (`hibernate.cfg.xml`, `hibernate.properties` or the config class)?

Comment: I don't have any code yet, I'm still in the thinking phase.
But I can give you a schema of both approaches.
https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=AB95C49E18AFAE1A!112872&authkey=!AEkvKTqJ7Om7RCQ&ithint=file%2cpdf

The first schema is with different tables to link roles for different objects. So user to user, role to user, role to sensor, role to user, role to pages and role to rest call.
These are 6 tables to give roles/users access to different objects.

In the 2nd schema I tried to unify it with 2 tables to give users/roles permissions on all objects.

Comment: Or can I just do this:
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-many-to-many-annotation-mapping-tutorial/

Does it matter of the MEETING_ID column in the jointable doesn't point to meeting. If meeting_ids without corresponding meetings in the meeting table are simply ignored then that's the solution.